# After upgrade to Angular 9 cannot find variable in typings file

Tags: angular, angular9

I have a reference to an external logging component (referenced in a js file), which I have defined in a typings file

**typings.d.ts**

```
declare var LogglyTracker;
```

I have upgraded my angular application from version 8 to 9, and now when I run **ng build**, I get the following error

> ERROR in src/app/error/loggly.service.ts:13:29 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'LogglyTracker'.

Does anyone know what the recommended way to fix this problem is? This code worked fine in Angular 8.

```
@Injectable()
export class LogglyLoggerService {

// https://github.com/loggly/loggly-jslogger
private loggly: any = new LogglyTracker(); //!! Error here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for me the resolution was to add the following to the top of service file:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings.d.ts" />
```

reference is apparently another way to import type definitions into code, more info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. If you have a lot of these files it is not maintainable. There must be another solution.

Comment: This shouldnt be a problem

Answer (score 15):

Had the same problem after migrating from **Angular 7** to **Angular 9**.

I personally just had to add one line in `tsconfig.app.json`.

**Before**:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "main.ts",
        "polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

**After**:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "types": [
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "files": [
        "main.ts",
        "polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.d.ts",
        "typings.d.ts" // add this line
    ]
}
```

---

I assumed you already made changes in `tsconfig.json` before migrating to Angular 9. If not, here it is:

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types",
            "src/typings.d.ts"
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem as the author - after upgrade to Angular 9, my local type definitions were no longer found.

In Angular 8, I added references to them in `tsconfig.json`

```
"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "../src/typings/my-lib/index.d.ts"
    "node_modules/@types"
  ]
```

After upgrading to Angular 9, `my-lib` was no longer found.
I generated a new app using Angular 9 CLI, and found that 2 files reside in different locations:

- `src/tsconfig.app.json` -> `tsconfig.app.json`
- `src/tsconfig.spec.json` -> `tsconfig.spec.json`

I made similar change in my migrated project, updated references to these files in `angular.json`, and corrected pointers to other files in `tsconfig.app.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json`

As a result, my `tsconfig.app.json` looks like:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Note that all `d.ts` files placed under `src` directory will be pulled in automatically (no reference in `typeRoots` section of `tsconfig.json` is necesssary)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 9 add to file `tsconfig.app.json` (because it resides in `src` folder, so `*.d.ts` are under `app` folder):

```
  "include": [
      "app/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding `typings.d.ts` inside `tsconfig.app.json` worked for me, don't forget to re-serve your app after saving the file.

```
"include": [
"src/**/*.d.ts",
"typings.d.ts"
]
```

Angular v.9